# RoR POST request results in Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm attempting a rudimentary API, but I'm at somewhat of a crossroads and I'm not too sure how to proceed. The general gist is that I'm provided a username and password to /authenticate.json and in return receiving an access token.

If I make a GET request, I get the information I require. If I attempt to do it via POST it throws the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>#<User access_token: "8922a3718bbe2a441a5ddddece3053a647941863b5ff2cad007...">}
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/authenticate' => 'user_functions#authenticate', :via => [:post, :get]
```

The authenticate definition within the controller looks like this (I know it's cludgy, I'm not exactly fluent with RoR / Ruby)

```
def authenticate
if params['email'] and params['password']
  userSearch = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['email = ?', params[:email]], :limit => 1)
  if userSearch.count == 1 
    hash = Digest::SHA2.new << "#{userSearch.first.password_salt}#{params['password']}"
    if hash.hexdigest == userSearch.first.password_hash
      access_array = {"access_token" => userSearch.first.access_token}
      userAccessDetails = User.find(userSearch.first.id, :select => "access_token")
      respond_with userAccessDetails
    else
      respond_with 'Invalid credentials'
    end
  else
    respond_with 'Failed'
  end
else
  respond_with 'No credentials provided'
end
```

end

If anyone is able to help or point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the user object you're passing has no id . In your query you only select the access token.

Try to also select the id :

userAccessDetails = User.find(userSearch.first.id, :select => "access_token, id")